# Mocking a function call of a class instance which is a member of another class instance in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am using Python2.7 and modules `unittest` and `mock` for this version. I have a situation where I'd like to mock a function call of an instance of a class and its return value. The trouble is, this instance is a member of an instance of a different class. Let me clarify in code.

Let's say I have a class `Bin` defined in `my_package/bin.py`:

```
class Bin():
    def __init__(self):
        # code to initialize other stuff
        self.rubbish = self.fill_with_rubbish()  # creates list of rubbish instances

    def inspect_rubbish(self):
        inspection_results = []
        for rubbish in self.rubbish:
            inspection_results.append(rubbish.inspect())
```

I also have class `Rubbish` defined in `my_package/rubbish.py`:

```
class Rubbish():
    def __init__(self):
        # initialization stuff

    def inspect(self):
        return 'Nice rubbish'
```

Now, in my `/tests` folder I have a test file `test_bin.py` where I set up the environment and import the bin and rubbish as follows:

```
import my_package.bin as _bin
import my_package.rubbish as _rubbish
```

and I am trying to test the `inspect_rubbish()` of the `Bin` class. The above is, obivously, not my production code, but in my original code I'd like to be able to modify the retun value of `inspect` of the `Rubbish` isntance and do various `assert` calls on it to check for how many times it has been called and so on.

I have been sort of stuck on how to actually mock the methods of the Rubbish instances of the Bin instance. I have tried to tackle the problem with some patching but to no avail.

```
def test_inspect_rubbish(self):
    with patch('my_package.bin.Bin', autospec=True) as mock_bin, \
        patch.object('my_package.rubbish.Rubbish.inspect') as mock_inspect:

        mock_inspect.return_value = 'Bad rubbish'

        bin = _bin.Bin()
        bin.rubbish = [MagicMock(), MagicMock()]
        result = bin.inspect_rubbish()

        mock_inspect.assert_called()
```

But this code fails with `AssertionError: Expected 'inspect' to have been called.` so I guess it is not doing what I intend it to at all. How would I go about mocking this behaviour and doing assertions on it afterwards?

Comment: Because you mocked `Bin`, `bin.inspect_rubbish()` is a mock call which doesn't do anything. Why are you mocking `Bin`?

Comment: @AlexHall The actual real world instance is quite complex and needs specific environment to be instantiated. Even if I get rid of the patch to Bin and leave only the Rubbish patch in, I still get the same AssertionError, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because you mocked `Bin`, `bin.inspect_rubbish()` is a mock call which doesn't do anything.
2. `bin.rubbish = [MagicMock(), MagicMock()]` means that the mocked `Rubbish.inspect` is never called, only `MagicMock().inspect` for each of those mocks.

This code works:

```
def test_inspect_rubbish(self):
    with patch('my_package.rubbish.Rubbish.inspect') as mock_inspect:

        mock_inspect.return_value = 'Bad rubbish'

        bin = _bin.Bin()
        bin.rubbish = [_rubbish.Rubbish(), _rubbish.Rubbish()]
        result = bin.inspect_rubbish()

        mock_inspect.assert_called()
```

Demo: https://repl.it/repls/RundownTastyKernel

I also changed `patch.object` to just `patch` because that gave an error.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer and sorry for replying a bit late. The code that you mentioned works great for the example but I am still hitting road blocks due to not mocking out the objects in my actual code. The actual class for which Rubbish is a proxy is non-trivial to instantiate which is why I needed it mocked out. Is there a way of doing this kind of testing with MagicMock objects?

Comment: Try leaving `bin.rubbish = [MagicMock(), MagicMock()]` and then `bin.rubbish[0].inspect.assert_called()`.

Comment: That seems to have worked quite well. If you'd like you can update your answer with that suggestion. Thank you very much for your help :).